# Method Not Allowed: The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: python, html, flask, web-deployment, decision-tree

I am trying to deploy my decision tree locally using flask. But I am facing the above error. here is my code

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>my flask hello app</title>
    <style>
        *{
            font-size: 30px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<input id="age" type="text" placeholder="age"/></br>
<input id="gender" type="text" placeholder="gender"/></br>
<input id="cp" type="text" placeholder="cp"/></br>
<input id="restbp" type="text" placeholder="restbp"/></br>
<input id="chol" type="text" placeholder="chol"/></br>
<input id="fbs" type="text" placeholder="fbs"/></br>
<input id="restecg" type="text" placeholder="restecg"/></br>
<input id="thalach" type="text" placeholder="thalach"/></br>
<input id="exang" type="text" placeholder="exang" /></br>
<input id="oldpeak" type="text"placeholder="oldpeak"/></br>
<input id="slope" type="text"placeholder="slope"/></br>
<input id="ca" type="text" placeholder="ca"/></br>
<input id="thal" type="text" placeholder="thal"/></br>
<button id="name-button">predict</button>
<p id="greeting">greetings</p>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script >
    $("#name-button").click(function(event){
        let message={
            
age:$("#age").val(),
gender:$("#gender").val(),
cp:$("#cp").val(),
restbp:$("#restbp").val(),
chol:$("#chol").val(),
fbs:$("#fbs").val(),
restecg:$("#restecg").val(),
thalach:$("#thalach").val(),
exang:$("#exang").val(),
oldpeak:$("#oldpeak").val(),
slope:$("#slope").val(),
ca:$("#ca").val()   ,
thal:$("#thal").val()   
            } // message bracket end

                $.post("http://localhost:5000/ahmed",JSON.stringify(message),function(response){
        $("#greeting").text(response.greeting);
        console.log(response);
    });

    });// onclick end
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Python COde:**

```
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
from flask import Flask

app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/ahmed', methods=[ 'post'])
def hello():


    message=request.get_json(force=True)
    age=float(message['age'])
    gender=float(message['gender'])
    cp=float(message['cp'])
    restbp=float(message['restbp'])
    chol=float(message['chol'])
    fbs=float(message['fbs'])
    restecg=float(message['restecg'])
    thalach=float(message['thalach'])
    exang=float(message['exang'])
    oldpeak=message['oldpeak']
    slope=float(message['slope'])
    ca=float(message['ca'])
    thal=float(message['thal'])


    import pandas as pd # load and manipulate data and for One-Hot Encoding
    import numpy as np # calculate the mean and standard deviation
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # drawing graphs
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier # a classification tree
    from sklearn import tree
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split # split  data into training and testing sets
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score # cross validation
    from sklearn.metrics.classification import confusion_matrix # creates a confusion matrix

    df = pd.read_csv('processed.cleveland.data',header=None)
    df.columns = ['age', 
                'sex', 
                'cp', 
                'restbp', 
                'chol', 
                'fbs', 
                'restecg', 
                'thalach', 
                'exang', 
                'oldpeak', 
                'slope', 
                'ca', 
                'thal', 
                'hd']

    df_no_misssing= df.loc[(df['ca']!='?')&(df['thal']!='?')]
    X = df_no_misssing.drop('hd',axis=1).copy()
    y = df_no_misssing['hd'].copy()
    pd.get_dummies(X,columns=['cp']).head()
    X_encoded = pd.get_dummies(X,columns=['cp','restecg','slope','thal'])
    y_not_zero_index=y>0
    y[y_not_zero_index]=1
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)
    clf_dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
    clf_dt = clf_dt.fit(X_train, y_train)

    import pandas as pd
    dict={'age':age, 'sex':gender,'cp':cp,'restbp':restbp,'chol':chol,'fbs':fbs,'restecg':restecg,'thalach':thalach,'exang':exang,'oldpeak':oldpeak,'slope':slope,'ca':ca,'thal':thal}
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='index').T
    if clf_dt.predict(dataframe)[0]==0:
        status="no heart disease"
    else:
        status="heart disease"




    response={
    'greeting':'Patient has , '+status + '!'

    }
    return jsonify(response)
```

Although both  the endpoints match which is ahmed but still facing the above issue. Moreover Both python and html use post request but python side is showing get request while html side is showing post request in command prompt

Answer (score 0):

`@app.route('/ahmed', methods=[ 'post'])`
You enable only `post` method if you want open page via `get` then you need to add get method

```
@app.route('/ahmed', methods=[ 'post', 'get'])
```

Comment: Also added get but now getting new error:    Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.